# Regex match any characters prefixed with a string and specific length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a JavaScript program where it validates input.

Requirement:

- Input will have a specific prefix. (eg: --NAME--)
- After this prefix, there can be any characters. (eg:
  --NAME--any-name_wit#-any*_special_char@#$%)
- Minimum length of total input (or length of suffix) should be 50 (for example)

I was able to write regex for the first two points, but I couldn't include the final point.
here is what I have tried for the first two points.

```
input.match(^--NAME--(.*)$)
```

Comment: Why not just do `input.match(^--NAME--(.*)$) && input.length>=50`?

Comment: Also, even easier to just do `input.startsWith('--NAME--') && input.length>=50`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pattern `/^--NAME--.{42,}$/`

`.{42,}` - This will match 42 or more characters. The total will be 50 including the prefix (`--NAME--`).

```js
const regex = /^--NAME--.{42,}$/

console.log(regex.test("--NAME--C$#V"))
console.log(regex.test("--NAME--C$#Vf34F#$f3ftbalc93h34vs#$3gfsddn;yu67u4g3dfvrv34f3f3ff"))
```

[Demo in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IaIBX1/1)

Comment: The question specifies the total input minimum length is 50 chars, but your code will mean the minimum length will have to be at least 58 chars

Comment: But now they have to change the number 42 in the regex string according to the prefix...

Comment: Yeah, if the specific prefix is known then regex can be generated accordingly. otherwise this won't work

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera this works perfectly. In my case prefix can vary, In your answer 48 indicates the minimum length of suffixes. So it saves me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead assertion for length:

```
/^(?=.{50})--NAME--.*$/
```

From start, at least 50 characters, starting with `--NAME--`.